# Calling external services which randomly timeout kills the ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout

So I have this web application (ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Site) which has at least 2,000 online users at any time. One of the most popular pages in my application contains data about user, and this data is not located in my repository, it is contained in some external vendor which is integrated into my system. So whenever this page is drawn I have to make a call to those services (currently there are 17) and than draw the page according to the data given by them. The data is subject to change in any given moment so I cannot cache it. Everything is working OK most of the time and the CPU utilization is 5% - 30% (depending on the number of online users of course). For each service call I have timeouts of 5000 milliseconds (for service references I set the `SendTimeout` and for the raw `HttpWebRequests'` I set the `TimeOut` property to be equal to 5000 milliseconds) Now suppose that one service is down, the CPU utilization of my server goes unxpectidly low like 3% - 8% and the application is lagging, I mean it takes some time to load pages (any page), for instance, if in a normal mood the response from my application would have taken (150-250ms) now it takes 1-3 seconds. I'm out of ideas of what to do. I cannot decrease the timeout because some services are taking 3-4 seconds sometimes so the 5 second timeout is the lease I can give. What can I do to prevent the late response ? I know it's bit general question. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a threading problem. Too many threads are waiting for response from the external service and they can not process other requests.

What I recommand you is to use Async Controller: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: That looks really promising. Let me try that out.

Comment: On my test cases the application is holding itself really great I see no slow responses at all. In few days I will try that on production servers. Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 1**

What if you replicate this data to your server? 
Meaning you can have another service, that works separately and synchronize data of external service with your server... and your websites always point to your local data... Right, this is some kind of caching, and web pages can show kind of old data... but you can set replication service to check data as often as you need...

**Suggestion 2**

Another suggestion that come to mind, can you use push notification instead? All the web pages open and wait, where server checks the data, and notify all the clients with the fresh data... in this case only one thread will be busy with external data, and all the opened users will have fresh data as soon as it is available. As a starting point, check [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)

Comment: I had that Idea as well but the data is really subject to change at any millisecond, So the data which is like 3 or 5 seconds old would be crucial to users. I am still keeping that idea in mind though.

Comment: That would really lessen the number of I/O threads occupied. I'll keep that suggestion in mind. Thanks